# Combine/Join RDD in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd

Here is my situation (Spark1.2):

- I have 2 Class : Dog and Cat.
- Dog and Cat have the attribute "personId".
- Person can have many Cats and Dogs. (Lists)

## I would like to have a result like :

`Iterable<<"PersonId", Tuple(List<Cat>, List<Dog>))>`

```
{
    {
        1,{{1,cat1},{1,cat2}},{{1,dog1},{1,dog2}}
    },
    {
        3,{{3,cat5}},{{3,dog5}}
    }
}
```

results from cat (personId,catName) :

```
{{1,cat1},{1,cat2},{2,cat3},{2,cat4},{3,cat5}}
```

results from dog (personId,dogName) :

```
{{1,dog1},{1,dog2},{2,dog3},{2,dog4},{3,dog5}}
```

result from clientwithkids (personId):

```
{1,3}
```

How would I do to keep only the Person who have Dog(s) and Cat(s).

This is what I've done so far :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<CassandraRow>> catRDD =
    functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "cat")
        .groupBy(new Function<CassandraRow, PartitionKey>() {
             @Override
             public PartitionKey call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                 PartitionKey partitionKey =
                    new PartitionKey(row.getString("personId");
                 return partitionKey;
             }
        }
    );
    --> [{1,{1,cat1},{1,cat2}},{2,{2,cat3},{2,cat4}},{3,{3,cat5}}]

JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<CassandraRow>> dogRDD =
    functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "dog")
        .groupBy(new Function<CassandraRow, PartitionKey>() {
             @Override
             public PartitionKey call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                 PartitionKey partitionKey =
                    new PartitionKey(row.getString("personId");
                 return partitionKey;
             }
        }
    );
    --> [{1,{1,dog1},{1,dog2}},{2,{2,dog3},{2,dog4}},{3,{3,dog5}}]
```

For only the "personId" appearing in this keyspace :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<CassandraRow>> keysRDD =
        functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "clientwithkids")
            .groupBy(new Function<CassandraRow, PartitionKey>() {
                @Override
                public PartitionKey call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                    PartitionKey partitionKey =
                        new PartitionKey(row.getString("bp"), row.getString("personId"),
                    return partitionKey;
                }
            });
            --> [{1},{3}]
```

What would be an efficient way to do it ?

Thank you for the help !

Comment: It's a bit confusing, can you show a sample data flow? data-in -> data-out.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit messy, I added an example..

Comment: I don't have an easy answer, but take a look at the new [Dataset API](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9999) coming in Spark 1.6 (out soon, probably end of the year) which should make this kind of thing easier.

Comment: @Ewan Thank you, but I should have said before : Spark1.2 (can't go higher..)